# version control of a Wordpress theme running in 3 different sites

Tags: wordpress, version-control

I'm maintaining a WordPress theme that is being used by 3 sites. But I need to customize the theme from each of these websites while there are still changes need to apply to all of theme.
What is a good way to control the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look into the **Child Theme** modifications.

Here from the official WordPress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

> A WordPress child theme is a theme that inherits the functionality of another theme, called the parent theme. Child theme allows you to modify, or add to the functionality of that parent theme. A child theme is the safest and easiest way to modify an existing theme, whether you want to make a few tiny changes or extensive changes. Instead of modifying the theme files directly, you can create a child theme and override within.

To make it short:

- The process is very simple, you will see it at the link above, with examples.
- Simply put all changes/customizations from each of your three website in a certain child theme.
- So you can update your parent theme at any time.
- Your child theme modifications stay untouched.

Comment: I've tried child theme but only style sheet can be import from parent theme while all PHP file will be override, which means if I want to do some changes I still need to edit all these files.

Comment: That's not right, you can put every file you want to your child theme. Look at the codex example. The example from above, with the css file, means that this is just the minimum for create a child theme, but you can add nearly every file from your parent theme to your child theme.